# Compare values based on variance

Tags: javascript

Consoder the following object:

```js
{
  valueA: 1000,
  valueB: 1001,
  variance: '+-5'
}
```

The goal is to compare if `valueA` is equal to `valueB` but with respect of the `variance`. In the example above the code should return `true` because `valueB` is within `+-5` of `valueA`. If `valueB` was either `> 1005` or `< 995` then the result should be `false`.

My problem is how to parse the `variance` property. To make the question even more interesting, the `variance` property can be in the following formats:

- `+-NUMBER`
- `-NUMBER`
- `NUMBER` (assume `+NUMBER`)
- `+-NUMBER%` (variance as percentage of `valueA`)
- `NUMBER%`

I could write some basic parser that is looking for specific characters (`+-`, `-`, `%` etc) and do some `if...then` or `switch` statements to capture the possible variants. But was just wondering if there is another, more general (?), approach to this.

Comment: No, you will need that parser.